# Is there any way that we can loop a function in a controller for multiple data validation?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm having a problem related to multiple data validation and want to know if there is any solution for loop condition of a function in a controller.If any please provide the solution.

I had tried using for loop but that dosent seem to work on Laravel Controllers

Comment: Do you have any code examples of what you have tried so far? We can't help much without seeing your current code.

Comment: To me seems some kind of "xy problem" question, please try to add more details: what have tried so far and what you expect as result. See here on how to post a [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can you post an example? What do you expect, what do you validate, where crashed loop..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide the relevant code of your problem to help us answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default laravel supports multiple rules for validation, you have add `|` between the rules, like `required|numeric|unique:posts`. laravel will check the rules one after another.

Please add more details on your question and add your code.